# Reverse engineering on a php function

Tags: php, symfony

I know it isn't actually the reverse engineering

I have this function:

```
<?=$this->get('translator')->trans('dashboard.actions', array(), 'front');?>
```

I want to understand how to insert a function (using include maybe) that gets called when using that code.

I know the function name needs to be *trans*, and it has *3 arguments*, but how to define it? Let me put this in a more easy way: In a php script how do I print *Hello world* when using `$this->get('translator')->trans('dashboard.actions', array(), 'front');`

Comment: That's going to be hard to track down without having the source.  Have you tried searching for "function trans(" or a Translator class?

Comment: Can you show us the code for your class? Since your using `$this`, I'm assuming you're writing a method in a class..

Comment: That's Symfony code IIRC. http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/translation.html

Comment: Please don't try to think about the original code, think this like an isolated problem, where you have this: <?=$this->get('translator')->trans('dashboard.actions', array(), 'front');?> and the output needs to be Hello world

Comment: Do we/you know the output of the code above?

Comment: I'm confused what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a regular class method:

```
class Traslator{
    public function trans($a, $b, $c){
        return 'Hello world';
    }
}
```

Now, you only need another class method called `get()` that returns an instance of the previous class:

```
class Foo{
    public function get(){
        return new Traslator;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
<?php

class Traslator{
    public function trans($a, $b, $c){
        return 'Hello world';
    }
}

class Foo{
    public function get(){
        return new Traslator;
    }


    public function test(){
        ?>
        <?=$this->get('translator')->trans('dashboard.actions', array(), 'front');?>
        <?php
    }
}

$f = new Foo;
$f->test();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, whats the "?>" do right after the test function?

Comment: @DomingoSL - That's your code. I assumed you wanted to be able to print `Hello wordl` with that precise line. I suppose it had a purpose in the original script.

Comment: To downvoter: could you please explain the "This answer is not useful" feedback? If I've violated some Symphony taboo, be aware that there wasn't such tag when I posted my answer.

Comment: Ummm, Im a bit confuse about how to use it, lets suppose I put your code in one php script call try.php and in another file content.php i have several lines of php+html code where there are several $this->get('translator')->trans('dashboard.actions', array(), 'front') how can i combine them?

Comment: Ive tried     public function test(){
        return include('content.php');
    } but it does not worked

Comment: Solved the problem! i haven't activated the short tags

Comment: I don't think comments are the best place to make follow-up questions, but you're also asking things that can be easily checked in the manual. E.g., what does `include` return? See [include](http://php.net/include): *Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files.*

Answer (score 0):

`$this` references the current object instance, and that variable may not be re-assigned. Meaning, to trick PHP into doing what you want requires to add code before and *after* the line you mention.

By creating a single class, the result can be obtained.

Before the `<?=...` line

```
<?php
    class C {
        function get($s) {
            return $this;
        }
        function trans($s, $a, $f) {
            return 'Hello world';
        }
        function hw() {
?>
```

Then the line

```
<?=$this->get('translator')->trans('dashboard.actions', array(), 'front');?>
```

Then need, to end the class, and call the method that does what you want

```
<?php
}}
    $i = new C();
    $i->hw();
```

Put the 3 blocks of code into a file and call PHP on it, the `<?=...` line should show "Hello world".

Answer (score 0):

`$this->get('translator')` return instance of class lets call it "Translator" - on that instance you call `trans()` method

so you would like to change instance of "Translator" to your extended version

```
class ExtTranslator extends Translator{
    public function trans($params){
        echo 'fdsfds'; // here you could add what you like
        return parent::trans($params);
    }
}
```

and yes - it's hard to help you cause I don't really know what are you trying to do - to work with that code you must first understand it...